# Does VB.NET 2010 support arrays of anonymous objects?

Tags: vb.net, anonymous-types

In C#, one can create an array of anonymous objects with `new []`.  This was not supported in earlier versions of VB.NET, but [a comment by Chris Dwyer in another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849836/anonymous-class-initialization-in-vb-net) suggests to me that it might be supported in VB.NET 2010.  I haven't been able to confirm this though.

Does VB.NET 2010 support arrays of anonymous objects?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it does. You can write one like this:

```
Dim values = {New With {.First = "Matt"}, New With {.First = "Mallory"}}
```

Updated: I removed the not needed () after values as pointed out by Ahmad Mageed

Comment: Thanks for your response. I probably was unclear in my original question. `Dim values()` is different from C#'s `new []`, right?

Comment: you can use `Dim values` without the `()`.

Comment: @Slack C#'s `new[]` would be equivalent to the first and last curly braces that indicate an array of items in VB.NET. VB.NET's `Dim values` would be `var values` in C#.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I get it now.  C#'s `new []` is just handled by `{ }` in VB.NET.  Was this the case prior to VB.NET 2010?

Comment: One key to note is the COmpiler definition.  If you have `Option Strict On`, `Option Infer Off`, and/or `Option Explicit On` then you must declare the object explicitely and still get the same effect.

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm C# developer, I'm stuck with VB code, I need to convert below code to VB.net. any help?


return Json(new
                {

                    rows = data.Select(x=> new
                    {
                        id = x.Id,
                        data = new[] {x.UdaName,
                        x.UserLogin}
                        ,
                    })
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);'