# How to convert this C# code to VB, "context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Consider this C# code:

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

When I use Telerik's online [C# to VB converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to translate the following code, I get an error on this line:

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", New () {"*"})`
```

The error is:

> cannot resolve response

My input file looks like this:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

And that translates to the following:

```
Public Class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider
    Inherits OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    Public Overrides Function ValidateClientAuthentication(context As OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext) As Task
        context.Validated()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context As OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext) As Task

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", New () {"*"})

        Using _repo As New AuthRepository()
            Dim user As IdentityUser = Await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password)

            If user Is Nothing Then
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.")
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Dim identity = New ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType)
        identity.AddClaim(New Claim("sub", context.UserName))
        identity.AddClaim(New Claim("role", "user"))

        context.Validated(identity)

    End Function
End Class
```

How can I correct the translation to get the resulting Visual Basic code to work?

Comment: whats your question ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation of that statement does not appear to be correct, it should be

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", { "*" })
```

without the New()

Comment: I try that already and it works that way but I thought the object param suppose to be an array of {*} please correct me if I'm wrong and thanks for the answer

Comment: @Xvegas {"*"} creates an array of Strings with a single element ("*").

Comment: I'm a c# guy but if I understand this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799403/does-vb-net-2010-support-arrays-of-anonymous-objects) correctly then in VB.net `{..}` creates an anonymous type and the array is implied equivalent to `new[] { ... }` in c#. I think anyway